# Required request part 'file' is not present error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload profile image to server using multipart file upload.
My code is

```
func uploadPhoto(image: UIImage, filePath: String, completion: @escaping uploadPhotoClosure) {
    
    let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3)
    
    let url = "https:www.somepath.com/uploadFile"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let boundary = UUID().uuidString
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
    request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    
    var body = Data()
    
    body.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("field_mobileinfo_image".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    
    body.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files[field_mobileinfo_image]\"; filename=\"img.jpg\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append(imageData!)
    body.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    
    request.httpBody = body
    self.serviceManager.async(request: request) { (innerClosure) in
        do {
            let response = try innerClosure()
            guard let json = response.jsonObject else {
                completion({ throw JSONErrorType.parsingError })
                return
            }
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
            let responseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(EditProfilePhotoUploadResponse.self, from: jsonData)
            completion({ return responseModel })
        } catch {
            completion({ throw error })
        }
    }
}
//servicemanager class
func async(request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping ServiceManagerAsyncCompletion) {
    ServiceManager.log(request)
    
    let task = self.urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion({ throw error! })
            }
            return
        }
        
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion({ throw ServiceErrorType.invalidResponse })
            }
            return
        }
        
        ServiceManager.log(response, withBody: data)
        //here handling status code
        
    }
}
```

And the error from server is below

> {
> "status" : 500,
> "message" : "Required request part 'file' is not present",
> "timestamp" : "2022-08-05T05:30:55.415+0000",
> "path" : "/uploadFile",
> "error" : "Internal Server Error"
> }

Any suggestions?

Comment: Keep it simple, I prefer to use `URLRequest`. Declare bodyParameters as `var bodyParameters = [String : Any]()`. Add anything you want to then convert it to Data using `JSONSerialization.data`. Go through the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest

Comment: Just looking over your code it seems you are not using the boundary the right way. It should be `--boundary--` for the last one.

Comment: @burnsi I have tried this //        let boundary = UUID().uuidString
as well, but same error happening

Comment: That´s not what I said and meant. The last boundary **has** to end with to additional ticks. The content of the boundary is not important as long as it is unique and constant throughout the request and starts with two "--".

Comment: Also if you can do this through a webbrowser, I would recommend debbuging that with a *man in the middle* client. So you know the exact formating. Then do the same with your App and compare.

Comment: If you have suggestions in this code, Can you post your solution in answer @burnsi

Answer (score 0):

As your code does not contain a reproduclible example, this is just a long shot.

The final boundary is definitely wrong. It has to end with two "-" ticks.

e.g.

```
body.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

but there might be more going on here.

[Good article on multipart form data](https://roytuts.com/boundary-in-multipart-form-data/)

[RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.html)

The boundary header can be an arbitary string. But it has to be unique in the request to seperate it from the datastream. Also in the body it has to start with two "-" and the last boundary line in the request has to end with two "-" ticks also.

Comment: Its not helped me still, getting Required request part 'file' is not present error with 500 status code

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative then you might have multiple problems here. Try to take my advice on debugging this. Without more information it will be hard to tell whats going on.

Comment: for Android they did this way and worked well with below code,
val file = fileInfo.asRequestBody("file".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileInfo.name, file)

Multipart
POST("/uploadFile")
suspend fun uploadProfilePhoto(
    Part file: MultipartBody.Part
): GenericMessageResponse

Not getting where iOS doing wrong this case